# TypeScript: How can I accept generic types that interact?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

longtime typescript veteran here, but i'm stuck making proper types for an rpc api system. i've boiled it down to this simple example:

```js
export function augment<
    Data,
    Method extends (data: Data, ...args: any[]) => void,
  >(method: Method) {

  return method
}

const example1 = augment<string>((data, x: number) => {})
  //                     ^
  // ERROR: Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1. ts (2558)

const example2 = augment<string, any>((data, x: number) => {})
  //                                   ^
  //            must be automatically known (string, not any)


const example3 = augment<string, any>((data, x: number) => {})
  //  ^
  // must preserve the method type, should be:
  //   (data: string, x: number) => void
```

- it appears generics must be passed "all or nothing"
- i can't seem to just provide the `Data` type without also providing `Method` type
- however i don't know the `Method` type ahead of time. it's usually defined inline in the `augment` function call
- so i need the `augment` function to receive the `Method` type as inferred from the `method` input
- my actual use-case is more complex: i'm really accepting a recursive object structure which can contain any number of methods, all of which will accept the same `Data` type first argument
- it's vital that the returned method has the *exact* type of the `method` input, since the methods will be literally defined inline the function call (can't use `typeof method`)

is there a different approach? if this is a typescript limitation, what workarounds or compromises might be considered?
   thanks

Comment: Translating the answers from the questions this duplicates to your code yields [this](https://tsplay.dev/Qmb6dm)

Comment: @jcalz — woah, fantastic speed! this solves the issue, thanks!